# Angular / xng-breadcrumbs disappear on page reload

Tags: angular, xng-breadcrumb

I've added xng-breadcrumbs to my Angular 9 app. The breadcrumbs are empty after page reload. Minimal reproducible example is: [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdxlrx), where navigating to parent/child2 route renders the breadcrumbs but reloading wipes them out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by injecting the `BreadcrumbService` in your `AppComponent`:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService) {}

}
```

Comment: Why/how does that work? The BreadcrumbService is reconstructed in the App component (or whichever component it is first injected into). But how does the router work with child-page reloads?

Comment: My guess is that if the service isn't instantiated until a child component is constructed, it's missed the opportunity to adjust the state for the root component.